# EXCEL VBA Create an Interaction of two Arrays

Tags: arrays, vba

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = Array("a","b","c")
array2 = Array("A","B","C")
```

How do I create a third one based on `array1` and `array2`:

```
array3 = Array("a_A","a_B","a_C","b_A","b_B","b_C","c_A","c_B","c_C")
```

**{EDIT}**

This returns an

> Error-13 Type mismatch

```
Dim array3 As Variant
ReDim Preserve array3(0)
For i = 1 To arrayCount1
    For j = 1 To arrayCount2
        ReDim Preserve array3(1 To UBound(array3) + 1) As Variant
        array3(UBound(array3)) = array1(i - 1) + "_" + array2(j - 1)
    Next j
Next i
```

The real question is how to initiate an empty array and put elements into it one by one.

Comment: With 2 nested loops.

Comment: If you know the dimensions in advance why not use just one `ReDim Preserve` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, like this:-

```
Private Sub TestMergeArrays()

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Arr1 = Array("a", "b", "c")
    Arr2 = Array("A", "B", "C")
    Arr = MergeArrays(Arr1, Arr2)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(i),
        If i Mod 7 = 6 Then Debug.Print
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function MergeArrays(Arr1, Arr2) As Variant
    ' 27 Oct 2017

    Dim Fun() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim n As Long

    ReDim Fun((UBound(Arr1) + 1) * (UBound(Arr2) + 1) - 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(Arr2)
            Fun(n) = Arr1(i) & "_" & Arr2(j)
            n = n + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    MergeArrays = Fun
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

dim array1 as variant
dim array2 as variant
dim array3 as variant

dim i as integer
dim j as integer

array1=("a","b","c")
array2=("A","B","C")

Redim array3(UBound(array1)+1,UBound(array2)+1) as Variant

for i=0 to UBound(array1)
for j=0 to UBound(array2)
array3(i+1,j+1)=array1(i)+"_"+array2(j)
next j
next i

End sub
```

Just found out a 2-dimension array needs a Redim with both its row's and column's depth first.